# App crashes without any logs when using some plugins to access device Contacts

Tags: crash, flutter, contacts

I want to show contacts in my app for which I tried using [contacts_service](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service) and [contacts_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_plugin) but my app crashes when I run it after installing the packages. I have just imported the file and written no code. I don't see any logs also.

Any other way of integrating contacts in my app would also be of great help!

Comment: Something else feels wrong if you are getting crashes and no logs. Maybe include which IDE you are using, eg Android Studio. How did you install the packages, have you run flutter packages get, flutter doctor and things like that, include the output.

Comment: For sure you should have feedback from your tools. Please provide the information asked by Ian and post your `pubspec.yaml` file too. Moreover you are getting error running the Android or iOS project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to learn and master the tools you need to use to develop Flutter applications.

And you really need to explain better your needs when you post a question on SO.

That said I've had a quick try on [contacts_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_plugin) and [contact_service](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service).

Do not use both, they are made for the same purpose. Choose one or the other.

It seems that `contact_service` is more stable: *a weighted score of 92 over 82*.

**Android**

Trying using `contacts_plugin` I guess you jad this error:

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'contacts_plugin' is using version 1.2.30.
```

That because the `contacts_plugin` use kotlin version `1.2.30` and you have AS >= 3.2 like me.

[`ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'`](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-contacts-plugin/blob/develop/android/build.gradle).

If you wanna give this a try you can clone the project and include the dependency this way:

```
contacts_plugin:
    path: ../flutter-contacts-plugin/
```

and change in the plugin build.gradle this line:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
```

with this

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
```

Even the iOS Project has problems if you use `contact_plugins`.

**`contact_serivce` instead it works fine either on Android and on iOS.**

Anyway always remember that on Android you need to add this permissions in you `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

and on iOS make sure to set `NSContactsUsageDescription` in the `Info.plist` file

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
```

And create a Flutter project with Swift support.

You can use the [default example](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service#-example-tab-) provided by the `contact_service` plugin to start learning:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

void main() => runApp(ContactsExampleApp());

class ContactsExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/add': (BuildContext context) => AddContactPage()
    }, home: ContactListPage());
  }
}

class ContactListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactListPageState createState() => _ContactListPageState();
}

class _ContactListPageState extends State<ContactListPage> {
  Iterable<Contact> _contacts;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshContacts();
  }

  refreshContacts() async {
    var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
    setState(() {
      _contacts = contacts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Contacts Plugin Example')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/add").then((_) {
              refreshContacts();
            });
          }),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _contacts != null
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Contact c = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
                  return ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              ContactDetailsPage(c)));
                    },
                    leading: (c.avatar != null && c.avatar.length > 0)
                        ? CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: MemoryImage(c.avatar))
                        : CircleAvatar(
                            child: Text(c.displayName.length > 1
                                ? c.displayName?.substring(0, 2)
                                : "")),
                    title: Text(c.displayName ?? ""),
                  );
                },
              )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContactDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ContactDetailsPage(this._contact);
  final Contact _contact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar:
            AppBar(title: Text(_contact.displayName ?? ""), actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                ContactsService.deleteContact(_contact);
              })
        ]),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Name"),
                  trailing: Text(_contact.givenName ?? "")),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Middle name"),
                  trailing: Text(_contact.middleName ?? "")),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Family name"),
                  trailing: Text(_contact.familyName ?? "")),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Prefix"), trailing: Text(_contact.prefix ?? "")),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Suffix"), trailing: Text(_contact.suffix ?? "")),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Company"),
                  trailing: Text(_contact.company ?? "")),
              ListTile(
                  title: Text("Job"), trailing: Text(_contact.jobTitle ?? "")),
              AddressesTile(_contact.postalAddresses),
              ItemsTile("Phones", _contact.phones),
              ItemsTile("Emails", _contact.emails)
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class AddressesTile extends StatelessWidget {
  AddressesTile(this._addresses);
  final Iterable<PostalAddress> _addresses;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(title: Text("Addresses")),
          Column(
              children: _addresses
                  .map((a) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                                title: Text("Street"),
                                trailing: Text(a.street)),
                            ListTile(
                                title: Text("Postcode"),
                                trailing: Text(a.postcode)),
                            ListTile(
                                title: Text("City"), trailing: Text(a.city)),
                            ListTile(
                                title: Text("Region"),
                                trailing: Text(a.region)),
                            ListTile(
                                title: Text("Country"),
                                trailing: Text(a.country)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList())
        ]);
  }
}

class ItemsTile extends StatelessWidget {
  ItemsTile(this._title, this._items);
  final Iterable<Item> _items;
  final String _title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(title: Text(_title)),
          Column(
              children: _items
                  .map((i) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(i.label ?? ""),
                          trailing: Text(i.value ?? ""))))
                  .toList())
        ]);
  }
}

class AddContactPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AddContactPageState();
}

class _AddContactPageState extends State<AddContactPage> {
  Contact contact = Contact();
  PostalAddress address = PostalAddress(label: "Home");
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add a contact"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                contact.postalAddresses = [address];
                ContactsService.addContact(contact);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.save, color: Colors.white))
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.givenName = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Middle name'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.middleName = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.familyName = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prefix'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.prefix = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Suffix'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.suffix = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone'),
                    onSaved: (v) =>
                        contact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile", value: v)],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-mail'),
                    onSaved: (v) =>
                        contact.emails = [Item(label: "work", value: v)],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Company'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.company = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Job'),
                    onSaved: (v) => contact.jobTitle = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Street'),
                    onSaved: (v) => address.street = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
                    onSaved: (v) => address.city = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Region'),
                    onSaved: (v) => address.region = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Postal code'),
                    onSaved: (v) => address.postcode = v),
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Country'),
                    onSaved: (v) => address.country = v),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```